# Missing Operating System Error When Rebooting from USB Drive

Tags: system-installation, usb, startup, reboot

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 and I want to install an older version like 14.04.4. I tried Startup Disk Creator and Unetbootin after formatting the disk with FAT 32 and NTFS, and also I tried these with two different USB drives in two different USB ports. But every time, after the message of "Missing Operating System," Ubuntu 15.10 started. I tried this different .iso files from different sources, and even a couple Win 7 .iso files.

Also I tried to install through Unetbootin's Hard drive option. Nothing showed up and 15.10 started again.

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron N5110 B45B45 with 500 GB Serial ATA (5400RPM) HDD, Intel Core i5-2450M (2.50GHz, 3M cache), 4096MB RAM(1x4096) 1333MHz DDR3 Dual Channel.

USB Drives are: Sandisk Cruzer Blade 8GB and SMI 8GB.

I really want to get rid of this version of Ubuntu, so any recommendation will be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to try to create the live-usb by the `cat` or `dd` command.

`Plug in` your `USB-Stick` or `card reader` with the card you wish to write to and:

```
sudo cat /path/to/ubuntu-*.iso > /dev/USB_raw_device_node
```

or

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu-*.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

To find out, what the `X` in `sdX` represents in your case, run the `sudo fdisk -l` command.

Comment: dd command worked but this time shows "installation crashed" errors in different points of installation. I think it's trying to install Ubuntu to USB drive, instead of hard drive and I couldn't change it.