# Missing Operating System when rebooting from USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

Trying to get my 15.10 to 16.04, but want to do a clean install as some of the PPA stuff messed up the OS.. Now I'm trying to do this for over 2 hrs now, following about 15 different solutions so far and not one worked out....and yes, i know it's  duplicate thread, but when I tried to ask on already open ones (like this one, what's the exact image of my issue: [Missing Operating System Error When Rebooting from USB Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750711/missing-operating-system-error-when-rebooting-from-usb-drive)) but I couldnt as this lovely site only lets you comment after getting points....
Anyway, first tried to use the USB I was when installed the 15.10 initially. The USB was a mess permission, but managed to clear it up and created the stick with Startup Disk Creator. Upon rebooting and choosing it I got the "Missing Operation System" error, then tried with unetbootin, same outcome. I ended up deciding that it was in fact the USB key being faulty as suggested at many of these workarounds to other people, so I tried unetbootin on HDD, but on boot, I just got back to 15.10...
Then tried it with an other 2 USBs with the exact same outcome... I'm getting really annoyed as I have no idea what the heck is going on as I'm through 20 solutions not one actually saving anything.....
Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: if your pc has the capability to write a DVD you should consider writing a DVD and booting from it. Here's a link that provides alternative installs ... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Answer (score 5):

I've had all kinds of problems with GUI based USB createors, and it sounds like this might be your issue as well.  You should be ***VERY*** careful with this command, but you could use "dd" from the terminal.  The "dd" command can destroy your instillation if you chose the wrong "of" aka "output file" path.  I've tossed in a step-by-step guide but feel free to Google "dd create bootable USB"

1. Open the "Disks" program ("Windows key" and type "disks")
2. Select your USB drive (should have a USB icon)
3. In the upper right hand side, click the button with three dashes
4. Select the first option "Format Disk..."
5. Leave defaults ("Quick" and "MBR/DOS") and click "Format"
6. Note the location of the "Device" towards the bottom of the window (in my example, it's "/dev/sdc")
7. Open Terminal ("Windows" key" and type "terminal")
8. Change directory to where your .iso is (mine is located in my Downloads directory, so I type "cd ~/Downloads")
9. Run the "ls" command to check the name of your .iso (in my example, it's "ubuntu-16_04.iso")
10. Run "sudo dd if=(your_iso) of=(USB_location)" (in my example, it's "sudo dd if=ubuntu-16_04.iso of=/dev/sdc")
11. Wait a bit for dd to finish.  Depending on how big the .iso is, this could take up to 15 minutes, and no progress is shown (aka, just chill until Terminal gives you control again, indicated by a blinking cursor after (username)@(yourMachine))
12. Reboot your machine and interrupt boot to select the USB drive (try key-jamming "ESC", "DEL", or "ENTER") and boot your USB

**Edited to provide a better walk-through**